# Merge dicts with different key types

Tags: python, mypy

When trying to merge dictionaries with different key types:

```
a: dict[int, str] = {5: "hohoho"}
b: dict[str, str] = {"hi": "hello"}

c = a | b
```

Mypy version 0.812 complains with `mypy_dict_merge.py:4: error: Unsupported operand types for | ("Dict[int, str]" and "Dict[str, str]")`

I expected mypy to infer a type `Dict[Union[int, str], str]`. I found that I can do

```
c = cast(dict[Union[int, str], str], a) | cast(dict[Union[int, str], str], a)
```

But that feels a bit clumsy, and there is no check that the `cast` makes any sense. Is there a better way?

**Edit:** As users have pointed out that I should just use different types in the first place - this is a simplified example, let's assume a and b just store the results of functions, and I cannot modify those functions. So

```
a = function_that_returns_dicts_with_keys_of_type_Apple()
b = function_that_returns_dicts_with_keys_of_type_Orange()
c = a | b
```

Comment: Don't explicitly type them as incompatible to start with? Define them as `dict[int | str, str]` instead.

Comment: Good point, but in my real world usecase that I deemed too long to include here, a and b are function return values. I don't want to modify those functions, but would still like to merge their results.

Comment: You can assign the returned values to appropriately-typed variables, though. Please do give examples that accurately reflect your context and constraints.

Comment: Again you don't have to modify the functions, just type the variables `a` and `b`.

Comment: Typing the return values `a` and `b` yields this error though: `error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dict[int, str]", variable has type "Dict[Union[int, str], str]")`

Answer (score -1):

It would be easier to instead declare the two dictionaries as the same type.
By declaring the two dictionaries as different types, we are needlessly adding a complication to the problem.

If you need to use the integer key value, this can be cast later on.
Try something like this:

```
a: dict[str, str] = {"5": "hohoho"}
b: dict[str, str] = {"hi": "hello"}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting to avoid the problem in the first place. However, the example is simplified and in reality the values are not constants but retrieved from functions, see my edit.